# Javascript Object watch

Tags: javascript

I use the next code for watch changes in javascript object: https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583

I have a next code for check updates:

```
var Obj = {
    prop: 0,
    inc: function() {
      this.prop ++;
    }
};

Obj.watch('prop', function(prop, oldv, newv) {
    console.log(prop);
    console.log(oldv);
    console.log(newv);
  });
```

// on button click i increment `prop`:

```
$("#btn").on('click', function() {
    Obj.inc();
});
```

When i run this code, and click button i get in console:

```
prop
0 
1
```

It's correctly.

But, when i click the next time, i get:

```
z
undefined
NaN
```

Online demo: http://jsbin.com/jenarapufo/2/edit?html,js,console,output

Why?

Comment: because u forgot to return new value from `watch` callback add `return newv;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return new value from `watch` callback. Update Your handler:

```
Obj.watch('prop', function(prop, oldv, newv) {
    ...
    return newv;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to return the new value from the callback:

```
Obj.watch('prop', function(prop, oldv, newv) {
  console.log(prop);
  console.log(oldv);
  console.log(newv);
  return newv;
});
```